# rails login facebook api debug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I'm using devise and omniauth-facebook authentication in my rails application.

Facebook has moved on to v2.x graph API. (deadline for api migration is April 30, 2015).

I configure my omniauth-facebook in initializer file as:

```
provider :facebook, ENV['APP_ID'], ENV['APP_SECRET'],
:scope => 'email,read_stream',
:client_options => {
  :site => 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0',
  :authorize_url => "https://www.facebook.com/v2.0/dialog/oauth"
}
```

But...how I can know that the calls are actually doing in the 2.x api version and not the 1.x I had before?.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could add the gem `http_logger` to your gemfile. You will then see the server-side http requests in your log:

`[DEBUG]   HTTP POST (123.07ms)   https://graph.facebook.com:443/v2.0/oauth/access_token`